# Passing array as command line arguments when running exe from batch

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file

The goal is to take the following array in a windows .bat file:

```
set SEARCH_DIR[1]="SomeValue"
set SEARCH_DIR[2]="AnotherValue"
set SEARCH_DIR.length=2
```

And to execute for example "someprogram.exe" with the values of SEARCH_DIR passed as individual command line arguments. I would prefer to do this as a loop or something rather than have to manually type out each element in SEARCH_DIR.

I found similar questions but none that answered it example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't find an example matching 100 percent
you could try on your own, that is what programmers do.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set SEARCH_DIR[1]="SomeValue"
set SEARCH_DIR[2]="AnotherValue"
set SEARCH_DIR.length=2

Set "AllArgs="
For /L %%C in (1,1,%SEARCH_Dir.length%
) Do Set AllArgs=!AllArgs! !SEARCH_DIR[%%C]!
Echo someprogram.exe %AllArgs%
```

Comment: Lol, well I wouldn't have posted if I didn't try. I don't know much about windows batch script. But thank you! I came close.